# find a some text in string bettwen some specific characters

Tags: python, wikipedia, findall

Hi I can select and put to list some specific text from string
for example, I have a string

```
"== example ==
Random text here
=== example2 ==="
```

I need select a text on example place and bellow an example but of another = stop example text put into a list together with text bellow but no exercise 2 only exercise without "==" and text below this list:
I will try it with this:

```
import wikipedia
page = wikipedia.page("Albert Einstein")
text = page.content

lst = []
l = []
n = 1
for pos,char in enumerate(text):
    try:
        if(char == "="):
            lst.append(pos)
            if lst[n+1] == lst[n+2] +1:
                    print(text[lst[n+1]:lst[n+2] +1])
                    l.append(text[lst[n]:lst[n+1] +1])
                    n =+ 1
            else:
                continue
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

expected output: ["Life and career", "Albert Einstein was born in Ulm(text bellow headers")

Comment: ...what is the exact output you want here?

Comment: Please clarify your questions more, I can't understand the problem here either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand that you want to extract strings which are present in between `== someString ==`, which essentially are headers of wikipedia page that you are searching for.

For these types of requirement, `regex` is what you need and not manual string index searching. Would suggest you to read about [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

Here is the code for your use case

```
import wikipedia
import re
page = wikipedia.page("Albert Einstein")
text = page.content
regex_result = re.findall("==\s(.+?)\s==", text)
print(regex_result)
```

`regex_result` is a list containing strings
Snapshot of `regex_result`
[image]

Comment: Yea but I actually can get a text under headers

Comment: Can you clearly explain what exactly you want as output

Comment: Thanks but I found a solution to this problem last evening.