# WIkipedia API get text under headers

Tags: python, api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I can scripe a wikipedia usein wikipedia api

```
import wikipedia
import re
page = wikipedia.page("Albert Einstein")
text = page.content
regex_result = re.findall("==\s(.+?)\s==", text)
print(regex_result)
```

and I can from every element in a regex_result(Wikipedia headers ) get a text bellow and append it to another list. I dug the internet and I do not know how to do that with some function in Wikipedia API.
Second chance to get it in get a text and with some module extract a text between headers more here: [find a some text in string bettwen some specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310135/find-a-some-text-in-string-bettwen-some-specific-characters/71310829#71310829)

I have tried this:

```
l = 0
for n in regex_result:
    try:
        regal = re.findall(f"==\s{regex_result[l]}\s==(.+?)\s=={regex_result[l+1]}\s==", text)
        l+=2
    except Exception:
        continue
```

But I am not working:
output is only []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call `re` twice, but rather iterate directly through the results provided by `regex_result`. [Named groups](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the form of `(?P<name>...)` make it even easier to extract the header name without the surrounding markup.

```
import wikipedia
import re
page = wikipedia.page("Albert Einstein")
text = page.content
# using the number 2 for '=' means you can easily find sub-headers too by increasing the value 
regex_result = re.findall("\n={2}\s(?P<header>.+?)\s={2}\n", text)
```

regex_result will then be a list of strings of the all the top-level section headers.

Here's what I use to make a table of contents from a wiki page. (Note: f-strings require Python 3.6)

```
def get_wikiheader_regex(level):
    '''The top wikiheader level has two = signs, so add 1 to the level to get the correct number.'''
    assert isinstance(level, int) and level > -1
    header_regex = f"^={{{level+1}}}\s(?P<section>.*?)\s={{{level+1}}}$"

    return header_regex

def get_toc(raw_page, level=1):
    '''For a single raw wiki page, return the level 1 section headers as a table of contents.'''
    toc = []
    header_regex = get_wikiheader_regex(level=level)
    for line in raw_page.splitlines():
        if line.startswith('=') and re.search(header_regex, line):
            toc.append(re.search(header_regex, line).group('section'))

    return toc
 >>> get_toc(text)
```